# Windows installer doesn't recognize SSD on Mac Pro

Tags: ssd, windows-installation, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro 4.1. I'm trying to install Windows on an SSD via DVD and I'm running into the same problem as described here: [Windows 10 install don't recognize SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/993878/windows-10-install-dont-recognize-ssd). Which driver should I get?

Comment: Are you using Boot Camp? Win10 isn't a supported OS for a 4,1, so the simplest method is to install Win7 then update it. If you want it on a separate drive, move it with WinClone after the install but before the upgrade to 10.

Comment: I have already installed Win10 on a hard drive without Bootcamp with the same DVD. I only need to do the same on an SSD now. I'm searching for the correct SATA controller driver.

Comment: The Mac uses the same type of controller for all the internal drives. Windows doesn't like being installed on externals of any type. We still don't really know exactly what it is you're trying to do, only what you think you need to do to achieve it. This is known as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to install Windows on an SSD via DVD

Use a Windows 10 Insider ISO on USB key to install Windows 10 (Insider)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-do-i-install-windows-insider-build-from-usb/9ff2977f-1c14-45a4-918f-419ca9263ed6

If you are running both on the same machine (MAC) consider using VMware Fusion or other virutalizer as there is a new Windows Insider build as often as monthly. I am doing another one now.